# Can I purge data from model objects in R?

Tags: r, object, tidyverse, lm, broom

I am estimating a large number of models ([lm](/questions/tagged/lm)-type, but possibly others) in [r](/questions/tagged/r). I do this ion a secure server, from which data export is restricted. I am allowed to export the results from models (coefficients, statistics) but not the individual-level data.

I could prepare an object that only includes relevant statistics from the objects and export this. However, it would be very useful if I could export the model objects themselves without the data but at the same time retaining functionality to predict new data, tidy results with `broom` etc.

I have tried to run, given m being an lm-type object: `m$model <- NULL` but this does not let me use e.g. `broom::confint_tidy afterwards`.

**Is there way possible to make my objects data-free and at the same time preserve functionality?**

I use [r](/questions/tagged/r) `version 3.6`, [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) packages. Thank you.

Comment: When I do a str() on an `lm`-object, I find the individual-level data for the model variables under $model, so I think I need to remove that part of the object to export it.

Comment: Your proposed approach is a security nightmare. For example, with an `nls` object you can find data in `nlsfit$m$getEnv()`, but there are also bits and pieces elsewhere that allow reconstructing (parts of) the data. It is extremely difficult to find for different model objects where data might be stored and methods often don't work if you remove it. You'll have to do your work the hard (manual) way. Forget broom.

Comment: Note that you can exclude the "model" part from the outset using lm's argument `model=FALSE`, and `confint(m)` will still work. Of course, residuals and fitted values are part of an "lm" object, so the observed response can be reconstructed. If data privacy is an issue, make sure to only export the summary statistics you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem the [butcher](https://butcher.tidymodels.org/) package is trying to solve.

If you want to remove data, the least you want to do is:

```
cleaned_model <- butcher::axe_data(butcher::axe_env(m))
```

And you might also want to remove fitted data, as having these, residuals and the model coefficients can allow for reconstruction of the model parameters of the original dataset.

Depending on the type of model, this will affect functionality. This means you'll need to test the functionality you want (only predicting, also residuals, also confidence intervals for estimates). Butcher will output which methods will be unavailable.